# Regex string between underscore

Tags: javascript, php

I need to get the markings between the underscores, for example:
Com_x0020_este_x002C__x0020_texto

Com`_x0020_`este`_x002C_` `_x0020_`texto

Thank you!

Comment: so you want the `x0020` bits all in an array discluding the `este` ?

Comment: If always 4 digit hex `(_x[0-9A-F]{4}_)`

Comment: Please go read [ask], and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for it preg_replace documentation can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php and the logic you are looking for it as follows:

## PHP Version:

```
 $string = "Com_x0020_este_x002C__x0020_texto";
 print preg_replace('/_(.*?)_/', " _$1_ ", $string);
```

## Javascript Version:

```
var $string = "Com_x0020_este_x002C__x0020_texto";
alert($string.replace(/_(.*?)_/g," _$1_ "));
```

Result: `Com _x0020_ este _x002C_ _x0020_ texto`

Comment: According to the tags, this is/was a Javascript question, not PHP ;-) Regex is still the same though.

Comment: @trizz According to the tags this was both PHP **AND** Javascript ;-)

Comment: @trizz However, I've now added the JS version for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, if I understand the question correctly: `/_(.*?)_/g`

See https://regex101.com/r/H3exx4/1/ for an example.